# rendering data in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, react-hooks

Please, help me with rendering data retrived from Firebase Realtime Database.

I succefully retrived data frome Firebase as an array. Next step is to display the data - here the problem begins.

The data I want to display should be stored in tableData state. At first, it's set as an empty array. Then data are retrived, state is updated by setTableData I can see the data as an array in my React DevTool - but component is not rendering (displaying) them.

I suppose that a propblem has something to do with lifecycle methods, because I can log the state in the console, but I can also see a pop-up info that the array (retrived from Firebase) "was evaluated just now". If I'm right, it means that the data are retrived after render method? What shall I do, to solve the problem and diplay data properly?

Here is my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db, auth } from "../config/firebase";
import {
  setDoc,
  collection,
  doc,
  addDoc,
  getDocs,
  onSnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import Form from "../components/form";

export default function Placard() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set up an auth state observer to get the currently signed-in user
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        setUser(null);
      }
    });

    // Clean up the auth state observer on unmount
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      // Get the user ID from the currently signed-in user
      const userId = user.uid;
      
      const retrieveProjects = async () => {
        try {
          // Create a reference to the user's projects collection
          const projectsCollectionRef = collection(
            db,
            "users",
            userId,
            "projects"
          );
      
          // Listen for changes to the projects collection
          onSnapshot(projectsCollectionRef, (querySnapshot) => {
            const data = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((projectDoc) => {
              console.log(`Project ID: ${projectDoc.id}`);
              // Retrieve the apartments collection inside the current project document
              const apartmentsCollectionRef = collection(
                projectDoc.ref,
                "apartments"
              );
      
              // Listen for changes to the apartments collection
              onSnapshot(apartmentsCollectionRef, (querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((apartmentDoc) => {
                  console.log(`  Apartment ID: ${apartmentDoc.id}`);
                  // Retrieve the doors collection inside the current apartment document
                  const doorsCollectionRef = collection(
                    apartmentDoc.ref,
                    "Doors"
                  );
      
                  // Listen for changes to the doors collection
                  onSnapshot(doorsCollectionRef, (querySnapshot) => {
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doorDoc) => {
                      console.log(
                        `    Door ID: ${doorDoc.id}, data:`,
                        doorDoc.data()
                      );
                      const dataRow = {
                        projectId: projectDoc.id,
                        apartmentId: apartmentDoc.id,
                        doorId: doorDoc.id,
                        width: doorDoc.data().porte_width,
                        height: doorDoc.data().porte_height,
                        thickness: doorDoc.data().porte_thickness
                      };
                      data.push(dataRow);
                    });
                  });
                });
              });
            });
            setTableData(data);
            console.log("Data retrieved successfully:", data);
          });
      
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error retrieving data:", error);
        }
      };
      retrieveProjects();
    }
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Placard</h1>
      {tableData && tableData.length > 0 ? (
        <table className="table-auto">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="px-4 py-2">Project ID</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-2">Apartment ID</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-2">Door ID</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-2">Width</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-2">Height</th>
              <th className="px-4 py-2">Thickness</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {tableData.map((row) => (
              <tr key={row.doorId}>
                <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.projectId}</td>
                <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.apartmentId}</td>
                <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.doorId}</td>
                <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.width}</td>
                <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.height}</td>
                <td className="border px-4 py-2">{row.thickness}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading data...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([ ]) ;
not null ... it should be work